# Remember/Forget device function on android app

Tags: android

I am building an app which connects & then controls a device.
I am wanting to add a remember device function and forget device function so the user can stick to one device or switch.

I am new to android so any help on how to implement this would be great.

Comment: Please explain down votes for future ref :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the information in SharedPreferences. If you are connecting to a Bluetooth device then you need to remember the **Mac** address of the device.

Store and retrieve the info using the following functions.

```
 public static void addDataToSharedPrefsString(String key, String value,Context context) {

    SharedPreferences.Editor sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(
                    context).edit();
    sharedPreferences.putString(key, value);
    sharedPreferences.commit();
}

public static String getDataFromSharedPrefString(String key,Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String value = preferences.getString
            (key, "");
    return value;
}
```

Add to shared pref by

```
addDataToSharedPrefsString("macAddress", "MAC123q4e",context);
```

get the shared value by

```
getDataFromSharedPrefString("macAddress",context);
```

if you want to delete an existing item in shared pref, set the value null.

```
addDataToSharedPrefsString("key", null,context);
```

I hope this is your requirement and this solution would help you.

Comment: Thank you! i will try this now :)